# Angular 2 (Typescript) - Remote development of components and dynamic injection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, babeljs

I'm evaluating Angular 2 as core technology for a composable administration console, whose main requirement is to be extendible and customizable. It should be possible for an external developer to develop his own component and inject it in some ways inside my "read-only" framework. Read-only means that developers won't be able to access (or edit) the source code of the framework. Instead they could simply concentrate on the development of the component's resources (.html, .ts/.js files ) without knowing the structure of the "master" app and serving them statically through servlets (or others). Is this at least theoretically possible? Can I have a "main" app module that dynamically imports (from a predefined location) declares and understands typescript-based components?

Answer (score 0):

Yep - see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fdP9Oc?p=info

I stumbled across this example randomly while looking at the Plunkr homepage.

You can pass components as object parameters to a function that compiles them.

```
import {Compiler, Component, NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Dynamic template:</h1>
             <div #container></div>`
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addComponent(
      `<h4 (click)="increaseCounter()">
         Click to increase: {{counter}}
       </h4>`,
      {
        counter: 1,
        increaseCounter: function () {
          this.counter++;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private addComponent(template: string, properties?: any = {}) {
    @Component({template})
    class TemplateComponent {}

    @NgModule({declarations: [TemplateComponent]})
    class TemplateModule {}

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    Object.assign(component.instance, properties);
    // If properties are changed at a later stage, the change detection
    // may need to be triggered manually:
    // component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```